# Observation with BufferedWriteHandler.flush

Tags: netty, flush

I've an observation pertaining to flush usage within my program. My test code pumps data < Channel.write(buffer) > worth 200 MB ( in chunks of 128 bytes each ) for approx 30 minutes with some delay of few ms between each such call.

Once I get call back to < SimpleChannelHandler.writeComplete > I log < System.currentTimeMillis + WriteCompletionEvent.getWrittenAmount >. Once my test is done with desired calls to < Channel.write(buffer) >, I observed that during the initial 5 minutes 55 MB worth data is flushed @ approx 1.6 mbps and then for the remaining 25 minutes it flushes 140 MB @ 0.8 Mbps. In the last 25 minutes I observed that the chunk of data written is in tune of 10 MB ( per callback to SimpleChannelHandler.writeComplete ).

The average delay in callback to < SimpleChannelHandler.writeComplete > is approx 2 ms for the initial 5 minutes of run and it bumps to 11500 ms for the last 25 minutes of run.

Please help me in understanding this behavior and suggest where I can tune to avoid the bump during the last 25 minutes of run.

Here is some information about my setup + code:

Connectivity between my client and server node is a 1 GE and I've set the < sendBufferSize > and < receiveBufferSize > in the ClientBootstrap.setOption as < 16777216 >

I've an instance of BufferedWriteHandler in my channel pipeline < pipeline.addFirst("bufferedWriter", new ConsolidatingAutoFlusher()); >, and in the < writeRequested > I invoke < BufferedWriteHandler.flush(true) >

Cheers,
Saket.

Answer (score 0):

So you call BufferdWriteHandler.flush(true) on every writeRequested(..) callback ? I don't get why you would want todo this. If you really flush on every writeRequested then there is not need to have a BufferedWriteHandler at all. It will just effect the performane in a bad way.

Comment: I tried with < BufferedWriteHandler.flush(false) > but similar observation.

Comment: My question was more why you need the BufferedWriteHandler at all ?

Comment: I nailed down the daemon by tuning the < sendBufferSize >, < WriteBufferLowWaterMark > and < WriteBufferHighWaterMark >. Thanks!